# shell script "tar" error while running in jinja2

Tags: shell, jinja2, tar

While running shell script in jinja2, I'm getting some errors.
Commond is:

```
resultFilesPath=/var/data/output
cd $resultFilesPath;
tar czvf {% for tar_file in outputs.output %}{{ tar_file.path }} ./* {% endfor %};
```

error is:

> tar: Old option 'f' requires an argument.
>   Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

I don't know the reason, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the error. Look at the man [page for `tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar). The option `f` requires you to specify the target archive file name:

```
tar czvf archive.tar.gz {% for tar_file in outputs.output %}{{ tar_file.path }} ./* {% endfor %};
```

Comment: In jinja2, "{% for tar_file in outputs.output %}{{ tar_file.path }}" is the target archive. I has known what's wrong with my script,  I changed output name, which is not "outputs.output" again, but didn't update it. Thanks anyway!